# How to position element middle of visible area of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table that has a height more than screen area and i want to place a specific element middle of that table. when user scroll the window(not the table) element should visible in the middle of visible area of the table. Is there a specific way to accomplish this with CSS,JS or Jquery?

[image]

Comment: `Position : fixed`

Comment: please share your code CSS and HTML so we can help you

Comment: `position: fixed` and then `left = (table.width / 2) - (element.width / 2)`. Repeat for `top`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `position : fixed` and have `top and left` as `50%`, to get the element in `center`, adjust `margin-left` and `margin-top` taking `width` and `height` of the element in consideration.

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;/* Half of the width*/
  margin-top: -15px;/* Half of the height*/
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..Elem..</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="fixed">Fixed Element</div>
```

Comment: Would creating an overlay not be just as easy? setting an element to 100% height and width of the table (or window) , and then vertically and horizontally centering it?  (Note: pulling this "overlay" forward using the z-index)